# Printing `$` on the screen

Tags: ruby, dollar-sign

How do I print a dollar sign to the screen in Ruby? I have information about the `$` variables. How do I print a `"$"` (or any other character reserved for a function or variable) on the screen?

Comment: Umm, like any other character? Your question is extremely unclear. There is nothing special about `$`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you ask about a problem you're having, it's very important to show us the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem. As is, we have absolutely no idea what you could be doing, resulting in a question that is vague and extremely broad, both of which are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character in string, with interpolated value:

```
val = 30
puts "$ #{val}"            # "$ 30"
puts "$ " + val.to_s       # "$ 30"
```

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn I tried that a dozen times and got en error every time, but now it works.  Maybe I had something wrong somewhere else.  Not embarrassing at all.

Well, ok, great, this was a waste of time.  Sorry about that.  Thanks!

Comment: When working with currencies, it's probably better to use a helper, so you don't have to manually insert the `$` everywhere

Comment: This can be used only when you want a space in between.

Comment: @sawa no, I just happened to put a space for readability and personal preference.  `puts "$#{val}"` would return "$30"

Comment: Right. And it only works with that order. You cannot use this for `"#$some_string"` order.

Comment: `#` is a special sigil which will be interpolated; in that case the `$` will be treated as a variable name.  You could certainly do `"#{val}$"` or `#{}$`; but in all cases the `#` is not outputted.  In that case, you would need to use the escape character, ` \ ` (backslash); or use a literal string (single quotes)

Comment: @vol7ron That is what my answer is all about.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about `$` in a string literal being interpreted as part of a global variable unintentionally:

```
$foo = "x"
"#$foo"   # => "x"
"#{$foo}" # => "x"
"#$bar"   # => ""
"#{$bar}" # => ""
```

then there are several ways to avoid that.

- Escape the `#`: `"\#$foo" # => "\#$foo"`
- Escape the `$`: `"#\$foo" # => "\#$foo"`
- Escape both: `"\#\$foo" # => "\#$foo"`
- Use single quotes: `'#$foo' # => "\#$foo"`

Comment: Uninitialized global variables have a value of `nil`, just like instance variables, i.e. `"#$bar"` returns `""` if `$bar` is not defined.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. I corrected it. Never mind my deleted comment.